# Time Machine backup on Samba share fails with errors 512, 20 & 14

Tags: mac, samba, smb, time-machine

I've set up a Samba share for Time machine backups according to [this guide](https://www.reddit.com/r/homelab/comments/83vkaz/howto_make_time_machine_backups_on_a_samba/).

My Mac recognizes the share correctly, but the initial backup fails with the generic error message that no Backup could be created on my share.

Running `log stream --style syslog  --predicate 'senderImagePath contains[cd] "TimeMachine"' --info` gives the following log:

```
MacBook-Air-2:~ xxx$ log stream --style syslog  --predicate 'senderImagePath contains[cd] "TimeMachine"' --info
Filtering the log data using "senderImagePath CONTAINS[cd] "TimeMachine""
Timestamp                       (process)[PID]    
2018-12-04 22:26:10.213195+0100  localhost backupd[34893]: (TimeMachine) [com.apple.TimeMachine:TMLogInfo] Starting manual backup
2018-12-04 22:26:10.338732+0100  localhost backupd[34893]: (TimeMachine) [com.apple.TimeMachine:TMLogInfo] Attempting to mount 'smb://pi@raspberrypi._smb._tcp.local./Time%20Machine%20Backups'
2018-12-04 22:26:10.897172+0100  localhost backupd[34893]: (TimeMachine) [com.apple.TimeMachine:TMLogInfo] Mounted 'smb://pi@raspberrypi._smb._tcp.local./Time%20Machine%20Backups' at '/Volumes/com.apple.TimeMachine.Time Machine Backups-74F8F302-361C-4490-9E35-1F2598F9D16E'
2018-12-04 22:26:11.816536+0100  localhost backupd[34893]: (TimeMachine) [com.apple.TimeMachine:TMLogInfo] Failed to find matching sparsebundle in directory '/Volumes/com.apple.TimeMachine.Time Machine Backups-74F8F302-361C-4490-9E35-1F2598F9D16E', directory contents: (
)
2018-12-04 22:26:11.845958+0100  localhost backupd[34893]: (TimeMachine) [com.apple.TimeMachine:TMLogInfo] Creating a sparsebundle using Case-sensitive Journaled HFS+ filesystem
2018-12-04 22:26:13.544412+0100  localhost backupd[34893]: (TimeMachine) [com.apple.TimeMachine:TMLogError] Failed to create '/Volumes/com.apple.TimeMachine.Time Machine Backups-74F8F302-361C-4490-9E35-1F2598F9D16E/A76BCEEB-A3BD-5D63-82F4-8AEBB2F5ACBA.sparsebundle', results: {
}, error: 512 Fehler 512
2018-12-04 22:26:13.548494+0100  localhost backupd[34893]: (TimeMachine) [com.apple.TimeMachine:TMLogError] Backup failed with error 20: 20
2018-12-04 22:26:13.621842+0100  localhost backupd[34893]: (TimeMachine) [com.apple.TimeMachine:TMLogInfo] Unmounted '/Volumes/com.apple.TimeMachine.Time Machine Backups-74F8F302-361C-4490-9E35-1F2598F9D16E'
2018-12-04 22:26:13.622367+0100  localhost backupd[34893]: (TimeMachine) [com.apple.TimeMachine:TMLogError] Failed to remove directory '(null)', error: 14 Bad address
```

The odd thing is: Contrary to the log a sparsebundle named `74F8F302-361C-4490-9E35-1F2598F9D16E/A76BCEEB-A3BD-5D63-82F4-8AEBB2F5ACBA.sparsebundle` actually gets created in my share. So write permissions definitely aren't the problem.

macOS 10.14.1
Samba 4.8.0

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the configuration I tried does not work with HFS+ formatted drives. Reformatting the drive with ext4 makes the error go away so the backup actually starts.